# How can I find the angle by the sin, cos, and tan without using the calclator?

Tags: geometry

What is the rule or law to find out the degree of the angle using sin, cos, and tan without using the calculator?
What does the calculator do to calculate the angles by given it the sin , cos, or tan ?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501660/is-there-a-way-to-get-trig-functions-without-a-calculator

Comment: You can use trigonometric tables. These have been available for hundreds of years.