# Matrix representation of complex numbers in exponential form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, complex-numbers

Do there exist matrices M and P for this equation? Or perhaps M and P dont need to be matrices? I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180849/why-is-the-complex-number-z-abi-equivalent-to-the-matrix-form-left-begins?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51292/relation-of-this-antisymmetric-matrix-r-left-beginsmallmatrix0-1-10-e) question after [googling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers) which made me wonder about whether the exponential form of complex numbers would still work.

$
z = a\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ -1&0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ -b&a \end{pmatrix} = Me^P
$

$
$

$
$

Addition:

I just found [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703448v1.pdf) article which I dont really understand, but where they solve a case similar to this. The thing I dont understand in this article is how you exponentiate with a matrix and what that alpha is doing there. Also I dont understand that in order to make this work they have to make the matrix $\Phi$ a complex matrix, looks like it defeats the purpose of having a matrix representation of complex numbers. Not sure whether to append this to my question or add as answer, because I still dont understand it.

They say,
$
z = \begin{pmatrix} a&jb\\ j\alpha^2b&a \end{pmatrix} = aI+b\Phi
$

Where,
$
\Phi = \begin{pmatrix} 0&j\\ j\alpha^2&0 \end{pmatrix}
$

For which they say, 
$
e^{\phi\Phi}=cos(\alpha\phi)I+\frac{1}{\alpha}sin(\alpha\phi)\Phi
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ with $i\theta=\begin{pmatrix}0&\theta\\-\theta&0\end{pmatrix}$. Calculate $e^{i\theta}$ and deduce $\theta,\rho$.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like $\rho$ and $\theta$ should be scalars then, right? Could you explain how you calculate $e^{\begin{pmatrix}0&\theta\\-\theta&0\end{pmatrix}}$?

Comment: Use the definition: $e^A=I+A+A^2/2+\cdots$ ; you'll see trigonometric functions appear.

Comment: Ah yes, it comes out nicely! Exactly nothing changes in how I calculate the magnitude and the phase as with normal notation: I ended up doing exactly the same as before. Is there a linear algebra way to calculate the "magnitude" and "phase" of $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ -b&a \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Let $Z=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\rho=\sqrt{\det(Z)}$ and $Z=\rho O$ where $O\in O^+(2)$. Bourbaki defines an angle as an element of $O^+(2)$, identifying $\theta+2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and $e^{i\theta}$. The effective calculation of $\theta$ is an analytic calculation.

Comment: Ah great, thanks. This gives me something to practice with.

Comment: Not sure what O+ is though. Google/wikipedia arent much help for that either. If im interested in group theory, do you know an online resource where I can look around? Otherwise Id just keep asking questions here :)

Comment: $O⁺(n)$ is the group of rotations in dimension $n$ (orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$).