# Ring Isomorphism Problem with complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that:

C=$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & b\\ 
  -b & a 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|a,b \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

is a subring of R isomorphic to the field C of complex numbers.

where R is $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & b\\ 
  c & d 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

I understand the concept of isomorphism but this question is a real stumbling block for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relation of this antisymmetric matrix $r = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 &amp;1\\-1&amp;0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ to $i$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51292/relation-of-this-antisymmetric-matrix-r-left-beginsmallmatrix0-1-10-e)

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix} = J$ satisfies $J^2 = -I$, so it behaves like $i$ does. In light of this, define the map from $C$ to $\Bbb C$ to be
\begin{align*}
C&\to\Bbb C\\
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix} = aI + bJ&\mapsto a + bi.
\end{align*}
It should be clear that this is surjective. Can you show it is injective? Can you show that it is a homomorphism of rings?